# Is my ball python hungry or not?

Tags: feeding, snakes

Okay, so I bought my ball python about 5 days ago from a reptile show. He is a one month old and the breeder told me he was due to eat today.

He seemed very interested at first and struck, but he missed. He then would not strike again. So I left it in his cage and it's still there.

I'm very concerned this is my first snake so I've never been in this situation before. Any help would be very appreciated thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When my snake is refusing food how long should I wait before I should worry?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/when-my-snake-is-refusing-food-how-long-should-i-wait-before-i-should-worry)

Comment: How old is the snake?

Answer (score 1):

Some ball pythons take some time to get adjusted to their new environment before they feel comfortable eating. Remove the food, avoid handling your snake for a few days and try again. Remember, it isn't uncommon for pythons to go quite some time in between feedings.

Also, ensure that the food you're feeding it is small enough for it to actually consume.

Source: [funwithlife.org](https://funwithlife.org/ball-python/food-list/#Help_My_ball_python_wont_eat).